# Common bottom view which is Present in all other views and it is pull-able in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I want to Show a common bottom view,which is present in all other view controllers even Navigation view doesn't hide this bottom view and this view has pull-Up, Pull-Down animations For Example Gaana App in AppStore

Comment: It is possible only you add the button on `Tabbar` controller  and present View when click or tap action. You user custom `tabbar` controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the button on keywindow of the app or make different view and call it on a single viewcotroller

second one is better than the first.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended use This library some modification you get you want [click here](https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController)